# upgrade a dependency of a global package in npm

Tags: node.js, security, npm

- `npm` version: `3.10.10`
- `node` version: `6.14.2`

I need to upgrade some dependencies of `npm` to address some security warnings.  An example: `sshpk` is a dependency of `npm` via `http-signature` and `request`:

```
bash-4.3# npm ls sshpk -g
/usr/local/lib
`-- npm@3.10.10
  `-- request@2.75.0
    `-- http-signature@1.1.1
      `-- sshpk@1.10.1
```

I need `sshpk` to get upgraded to `>=1.14.1`, which is possible given the version lock in `http-signature@1.1.1`'s package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "assert-plus": "^0.2.0",
    "jsprim": "^1.2.2",
    "sshpk": "^1.7.0"
  },
```

I've tried running `npm upgrade -g npm@3` and `npm --depth 9999 upgrade -g npm@3` without any success.  It seems that `npm` doesn't continue in any `update` action since it notices we're already on the latest `npm 3.x.x` release of `3.10.10`.  I need to be able to keep `npm`'s dependencies up-to-date as far as security patches go.  Is this possible through `npm update` directly?    I'm thinking of something similar to `yarn upgrade <package>@<version>` where it will traverse a package's sub-dependencies and upgrade those, even if the parent package isn't in need of a version change.

Comment: You can reinstall npm to install newer dependencies, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to reinstall the package is to remove it or `node_modules` and install again.

Since NPM cannot be installed without NPM, this requires [Node to be reinstalled](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/if-your-npm-is-broken).

An alternative is to install a spare NPM wrapper (e.g. [`npm3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm3)) and use it to reinstall main `npm` package

```
npm i -g npm3
rm -rf npm/
npm3 i -g npm@3
```

[`--force` option](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) can be used to reinstall the package, but it doesn't guarantee that package dependencies will be reinstalled.